# Не могу понять почему возникает данная ошибка при загрузке картинки в FireBase Storage

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.example.uchebnik.RegistrActivity.uploadImage(RegistrActivity.java:166)
at com.example.uchebnik.RegistrActivity.onActivityResult(RegistrActivity.java:155)

```
private void init()
{
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("ImageDB");
}

public void onClickChooseImage (View view)
{
    getImage();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            profileImage.setImageURI(data.getData());
            uploadImage();
        }

    }
}
private void uploadImage()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) profileImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,baos);
    byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
    final  StorageReference mRef = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "my_image");
    UploadTask up = mRef.putBytes(byteArray);
    Task<Uri> task = up.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            return mRef.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            uploadUri = task.getResult();
        }
    });


}

private void getImage()
{
    Intent intentChooser = new Intent();
    intentChooser.setType("image/*");
    intentChooser.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intentChooser, 1);
}
```

Comment: Если моё сообщение решило Ваш вопрос, его можно отметить принятым. Для этого, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тексте ошибки написано, что Вы применяете метод `child` к пустому объекту. Насколько я вижу, это относится к вот этой строке:
`final  StorageReference mRef = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "my_image");`
Это означает, что на этом моменте в переменной `mStorageRef` пусто. Этому есть несколько возможных причин.

1. Вы инициализируете эту переменную в методе `init()`. Возможно, Вы нигде этот метод не вызываете, и поэтому инициализация не происходит, и переменная остаётся пустой.
2. Вы прописываете путь до `ImageDB`. Возможно, Вы случайно опечатались в названии своей базы данных, поэтому переменная неправильно инициализируется.

Я склоняюсь к 1 варианту. Чтобы проверить, так ли это, перенесите строку инициализации (вот эту: `mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("ImageDB");`) из метода `init()` в начало метода `uploadImage()`

Comment: Спасибо за все ответы! Проблема тут заключалась в том, что не срабатывал метод init(), но метод я этот вызывал, перенес строку инициализации и все заработало

Comment: Рада, что смогла помочь! Успехов! :)